# Chrome Extension, How to Get The Time the User is active in one Tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am doing it in the background.js file.

I currently have this:

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(async (activeInfo) => {
  const tab = await chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId);
  console.log("tab", tab)
});
```